# Safari jquery issue - some of the scripts is not working

Tags: jquery, safari

There is some big problems with Safari v 5.0.3
It doesn't load some of jquery scripts, while it is okay in Opera, Chrome and Mozilla.
Here is my list of scripts connected:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=940" />
  <title>MTBank</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fonts.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/core.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/pickmeup.min.css" type="text/css" />
  <!--[if IE 9]><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie9.css" /><![endif]-->
  <!-- add necessary browser css here -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/objwatch.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mousewheel_plugin.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/popups.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/style.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/toggle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tabs.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scroll.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/treetable.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/checkboxes.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/selects.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/inputs.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/payments.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/emaillist.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/quickscroll.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/productblocks.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/cardslist.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/helper.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.pickmeup.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/finalize.js"></script>
</head>
```

Safari doesn't seems to load 3 last scripts, while it able to load the others. Since I cannot provide HTML and CSS code (because of security reasons), I am able to show you the scripts.

finalize.js - http://jsfiddle.net/H4ysn/

helper.js - http://jsfiddle.net/j3np2/

jquery.pickmeup.min.js (just a little code-adjusted jquery calender) - http://jsfiddle.net/u684R/1/

I just don't understand what could be wrong. Maybe it's a some sort of syntax error, or Safari cannot load more than some nth scripts position? I did enabled JS in Safari settings by the way.

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: There is only one warning about old function "getPreventDefault()", but there is no errors at all.

Comment: Check the Network tab to see if it's getting errors trying to load those files.